# Send notification to server about browser/tab close in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jboss

I have a web page `index.html`. I am trying to send a notification to JBOSS server about the tab close event.
My code looks like this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
            var msg = "\o/";
            (e || window.event).returnValue = msg;
            window.serverapi.send_close_notification()
            return msg;
        });
```

The problem with this code is that it prompts a confirmation dialog and sends the notification whether or not I choose to close it.

Is there a way to solve this? My only objective is to send a message to server when the browser or tab is **successfully** closed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon . Not a stardard yet, though.

Comment: What version of the JBoss AS or WildFly?